# Updates on Manjaro Error message during update

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-updates

I'm new to Manjaro, I have a little knowledge of Linux and I'm trying to learn more.

However I had a notification from Package Manager informing me that updates were available.

I then had a notification relating to "arc-menu" then after inserting my password got an error message "Error failed to prepare transaction
target not found: gnome-shell-extension-arc-menu"

I have tried looking for a solution but feel as if I'm getting no where.
I have attached 2 screenshots of the messages I get, any help would be gratefully excepted

[image: Transaction Summary][image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Gnome shell extensions to modify the appearance of Gnome? It looks like the package may have been re-named. If you don't know what this package does, it's not very important, it's just used to modify the Gnome GUI, and can be safely removed.

- If you don't need it, just open a terminal and run the following command:

  ```shell
  sudo pacman -R gnome-shell-extension-arcmenu
  ```
- If it says `error: target not found: gnome-shell-extension-arcmenu`, run the following command:

  ```shell
  sudo pacman -R gnome-shell-extension-arc-menu
  ```
- If you do want the gnome shell extension package, then first run the command(s) above and then run:

  ```shell
  sudo pacman -Syu gnome-shell-extension-arc-menu
  ```